# Python tkinter GUI listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

i want to disable a delete button on gui app which deletes the selected item . if there isn't a selection made the button should be disabled . is there a way i can do it? ill post my code below
`

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox


def delete():
    if lb1.curselection():
        b= lb1.curselection()[0]
        lb1.delete(first=b,last=None)




B2=Button(root,text="Delete",command=delete)
B2.grid(column=8,row=5)  
k=lb1.curselection()
if k[0]==0:
    B2.config(state = DISABLED)
else:
    B2.config(state = NORMAL)
```

`

Comment: You can bind the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event on `lb1` and in the bind callback set the state of `B2` based on the result of `lb1.curselection()`.  You should also call the callback at the end of `delete()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after` method here, as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox


def delete():
    if lb1.curselection():
        b= lb1.curselection()[0]
        lb1.delete(first=b,last=None)

def check_selection():
    k=lb1.curselection()
    if k:
        B2.config(state = NORMAL)
    else:
        B2.config(state = DISABLED)
    root.after(100, check_selection)

B2=Button(root,text="Delete",command=delete)
B2.grid(column=8,row=5)  

root.after(100, check_selection)
```

The `after` method will keep checking (every 100 ms) if there is a selection made in the Listbox.

**EDIT**

The value of `100` in the `after` method can be changed to any value that suits you. Just remember that the unit is `ms`

Comment: this throws an error  
  File "/tmp/mozilla_root0/law.py", line 31, in check_selection
    if k[0]==0:
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: checking the selection 10 times per second is rather inefficient.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes defintely. I was just suggesting that the selection can be checked in this manner. The OP can decide on a particular value. Maybe, I should have written this in the answer so as to avoid confusion

Comment: @FrainBr33z3                                                                                                                    `def Insert():
    s=lb1.size()
    name = simpledialog.askstring("Input","NAME",parent=root)
    if name is not None:
        lb1.insert(s+1,name) `   so with this function m able to add new value to listbox , but when the input is blank and ok is clicked then the space  or empty string is added in the list..is there any way to fix?

Comment: @scshivam please start a new question. It is easier and helpful for anyone else with the same problem. If this one is answered, please accept the answer.